# CodeIgniter file uploading

Tags: codeigniter-3

My current code is working on my local machine but not on live server.
Even I Have checked all the permissions and all the issue.
After `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` And  `$this->upload->initialize($config);`

this two lines it will not proceed. Please help me to resolve this issues.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting  ?

Comment: Hey I am not getting any kind of error there It just getting blank and unable to proceed the script

Comment: could you post the whole code which u are using to upload files. and have you created folder online where you are uploading file and make sure upload path must be valid. Because sometimes you will face problems becuase of uppercase letters or having spaces, etc

Answer (score 0):

You should add an image Library into your Program

```
public function imageUploadPost()
{
  $this->load->library('image_lib');
  $id=$this->input->post('image'); 
  $string1 = $id;
  $config['upload_path']   = 'Uploads/Products';  // directory
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
  $config['max_size']      = 40000;
  $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 10000);
  $config['file_name']=$string1."_".$milliseconds;
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
  { 
    $fileData = $this->upload->data(); 
    $uploadData[$i]['image'] = $fileData['file_name'];  
    echo $fileData['file_name'];
  }
  else
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please load  upload library properly

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```